# How does uncanny dodge work with invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, invisibility

Direct Quotes from http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/: (emphasis mine)

> **Uncanny Dodge** (Ex): At 2nd level, a barbarian gains the ability to react to danger before her senses would normally allow her to do so. She cannot be caught flat-footed, *even if the attacker is invisible*. She still loses her Dexterity bonus to AC if immobilized. A barbarian with this ability can still lose her Dexterity bonus to AC if an opponent successfully uses the feint action against her.
>
> **Invisible**: Invisible creatures are visually undetectable. An invisible creature gains a +2 bonus on attack rolls against sighted opponents, and ignores its opponents' Dexterity bonuses to AC (if any).

**My question:** Do you get your dexterity bonus against an invisible foe when you have uncanny dodge or not?

Invisibility does not specifically say that it makes the opponent you attack flat-footed, only that it denies them their dexterity bonus to their AC (which is not the same thing). However, Uncanny Dodge specifically mentions invisibility, suggesting that you get some bonus against it. So, as far as I can tell, either the wording is off and uncanny dodge allows you your dexterity bonus against invisibility, or paizo felt it necessary to point out that uncanny dodge keeps you from being caught flat-footed even if your opponent is invisible, for no reason other than to mention it (possibly for clarity).

Comment: A number of places on the prd have Uncanny dodge and some of them are worded different. The internal-alchemist has the same wording as Doc Snuggles' answer. It is likely the rules were updated but not the prd webpage.

Comment: The character-optimization hobby has certainly encouraged a strong interest in interpreting RAW. Despite this, RPGs are written for humans, not robots. The wording of Uncanny Dodge is imprecise, but the writer quite clearly intended it to be proof against invisible attackers, so you should probably interpret it as such.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Do you get your dexterity bonus against an invisible foe when you have uncanny dodge or not?

### Yes, you do.

The Pathfinder SRD states:

> Uncanny Dodge (Ex)
>
> At 2nd level, a barbarian gains the ability to react to danger before
>   her senses would normally allow her to do so. She cannot be caught
>   flat-footed, **nor does she lose her Dex bonus to AC if the attacker is
>   invisible.**

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Uncanny-Dodge-Ex-

Comment: Might want to add that this is due to the [official errata.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/resources)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still retain your Dex bonus (at least everywhere I've played).  You just don't get to ignore the concealment when you attack them back.

Answer (score 0):

An invisible creature is with no doubt at an advantage when sneaking up to someone and getting a surprise round on him.
It would be easy to think that a guy who has *uncanny dodge* could benefit from the feature by noticing someone even if he hasn't acted yet, but needs to be aware of the presence of its opponent.
*Uncanny dodge* cares to tell you that this is not the case.